# About the extrema of the function $xe^{-x^{2}}$ and an equivalence with another .

Tags: functions, derivatives

Hi it's a very simple question but here I'm just curious :

Let $x>0$ and define :

$$f(x)=xe^{-x^{2}},\quad g(x)=xe^{-x^{4}}$$

Then and it's a high-school exercise to show that the maximum of these two functions have the same abscissa wich is $\sqrt{0.5}$ using derivatives .

Now my question is very simple is there an analytical or algebraic path to show that the first maximum implies the second and vice versa (so an equivalence) ?

Thanks!

Comment: Hard to imagine a rigorous implication.  The best that I can offer is a (**lame**) explanation.  In considering the equation $1 + kx^{-k} = 0$, the roots at $k = 2$ and $k = 4$ are equivalent because $\frac{4}{2} = \frac{(0.5)^2}{(0.5)^4}.$

Comment: You can calculate that $g'(x) = f'(x) (1+2x^2)e^{-x^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is not quite what you were looking for, but if $s(x)=xe^{t(x)}$ for some differentiable function $t$, then $s'(x)=e^{t(x)}+xe^{t(x)}t'(x)=e^{t(x)}(1+xt'(x))$. Since $e^{t(x)}$ is always non-zero, the critical points of $s$ occur when $1+xt'(x)=0$. If $t(x)=-x^n$ for some positive integer $n$, then we have to solve the equation
$$
1-nx^n=0
$$
This equation has the solution $x=\sqrt[n]{1/n}$. And it happens that $\sqrt[2]{1/2}=\sqrt[4]{1/4}$.